# $.ajax wont work in IE 8

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, internet-explorer

I have tried to get my page to work in IE but this code does not work, it will not print out "Fooo!" as a Paragraf eg, nothing is shown. It does however do that in FF wihout any hickups;

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "foo.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml)              
            {
                var markup = "<p>Fooo!</p>"         
                $(markup).appendTo(".container");                                                           
            }
        });                                 
    });                     
</script>
```

If i make the printout without the "$.ajax" it works in IE without any problems. Works in IE;

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
                var markup = "<p>Fooo!</p>"                                     
                $(markup).appendTo(".container");                               
    });                     
</script>
```

*Edit Im now sure that it does not read the .xml i added the code;

```
error: function(r, s, e) 
{            
alert(s);             
alert(e);        
}
```

In the "$.ajax" and it resolves to "parseerror" and "undefiend" in IE. I have tried with diffrent XMLs that im pretty sure would work, this for example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<fooo>
</fooo>
```

*Edit2 I tried loading a xml from the web (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml), it resulted in that it worked in IE but not in FF (same fault as prev on IE, "parseerror" and "undefined") any idea?

Any suggestion why the $.ajax (xml-read) dont work?

Comment: Is `foo.xml` a valid XML file?

Comment: Please define `does not work`. Also add a semicolon after the `var markup = "<p>Fooo!</p>"`. Not really needed in this case but it prevent errors in the future.

Comment: Yes it is a valid XML. I will edit my post so it give a better understandig on what is happening, thx for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work after finding and reading this; http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

So for IE the input needed to be parsed.

The final code looks like this;

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "fooo.xml",
            dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",                            success: function(data)                 
            {

                var xml;
                if (typeof data == "string") 
                {
                    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xml.async = false;
                    xml.loadXML(data);
                } 
                else 
                {
                   xml = data;
                }
```

Thanks for all your help, really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your error function to see what error is causing the problem:

```
error: function(r, s, e) {
            alert(s);
            alert(r);
       }
```

EDIT:

Maybe try to add 'content type':

```
...
dataType: "xml",
contentType: "application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1",
...
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know that was possible. I get the Errocode "parseerror".

Comment: changed it a bit; Do you have special characters in your xml? Might cause the problem

Comment: I have my xml in the begining at the TS(somehow it did not show in the prev post). I get "parseerror" and then "undefined" using the code above, once again thx, im quite new to jquery-programming.

Comment: No problem, I'm not an expert either, just faced same kind of problem :)

Comment: Thanks, but did not help. Notice my edit. When i try to load an xml from the web (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) it works in IE but not in FF, same fault in FF as it was in IE. Confusing, does it matter where it gets the xml from?

Answer (score 0):

please try to change `<script>`

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

also :

```
 success: function(xml)              
            {
                var markup = "<p>Fooo!</p>"         
                $(markup).appendTo(".container:first");// I dont know how many you have...                                                           
             }
```

Comment: In HTML5, you don't need to set type. It's default to `text/javascript`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do only have one div. <script type="text/javascript"> is also added.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem? http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5273

Also tried to load XML from another page on the internet?

Comment: Good post, the first bug i dont think i im a subject to due to i im already using dataType: "xml". Now to the intressting part, i tried loading an xml from the web; http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml witch resulted in working on IE but not in FF, now im realy confused.